# ngClass changing class dependant on route

Tags: angular

I'm trying to change the div class depending on the route (/home)

I thought this would do the trick:

```
 [ngClass]="{'background_image':router.url === '/home'}
```

But it seems to not have the effect i was looking for..

Will I need to pass the route into a variable and feed it through the ngClass?

I cannot find any solutions online to this issue.

Comment: As per your code `background_image` is a css class you want to apply based on the route.

Comment: that's correct. so if my route is /example, the class will not apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a getter in to the component .ts file where the boolean value is calculated. For instance:

```
get isRouteHome(): boolean {
    // logic here
    this.activatedRoute.url === RouterPaths.home;
}
```

edit: I forgot that I usually make *[string enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums)* for my route paths (here: RouterPaths). It is then easier to use those variables across the app.

And in template:

```
[ngClass]="{'background_image': isRouteHome }"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only is declare in constructor Router as **public**:

```
constructor(public router:Router){}
```

Remember in .html you only can use variables public (by defect all the variables in Angular are public). BTW you can also use

```
[class.background_image]="router.url === '/home'"
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-14mupl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)